# Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/web/FetchCompileWasmTemplatePlugin'

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I have a Vue application which is running live and node version is 8. I have clone this application, I deleted the package.lock file and node_module folder, and run `npm i`, I have node 12.18 installed on my mechine, after successful installation, I try to run appplication by `npm run dev`, but getting error:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                   11:14:59 AM

 error  in ./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js

Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/web/FetchCompileWasmTemplatePlugin'
Require stack:
- C:\xampp\htdocs\easy-portal\node_modules\worker-loader\dist\index.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\easy-portal\node_modules\worker-loader\dist\cjs.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\easy-portal\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\easy-portal\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\easy-portal\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\easy-portal\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\easy-portal\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\easy-portal\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\easy-portal\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\easy-portal\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js
```

here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "ATS System",
  "author": "N4TECH",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build:dev": "node build/dev.js",
    "build:prod": "node build/build.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^1.4.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.8",
    "debounce": "^1.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-static-gzip": "^0.3.2",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "pusher-js": "^4.3.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "tributejs": "^3.5.3",
    "vee-validate": "^2.0.0-beta.17",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-clipboard2": "^0.3.1",
    "vue-html5-editor": "^1.1.1",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.1.0",
    "vue-pdf": "^3.2.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-scrollto": "^2.11.0",
    "vue-social-sharing": "^2.3.3",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "vue-truncate-collapsed": "^1.3.0",
    "vue2-datatable-component": "^2.1.26",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.16.0",
    "vuetify": "^1.2.4",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.6",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0",
    "worker-loader": "^3.0.7"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by update webpack to webpack5

Comment: Could you provide some more information to your proposed solution? Perhaps provide a step-by-step guide?